# Time to step down and let this be

Tags: discussion, moderators

It took me a while to make my head around this, but I feel it's time for me to leave.

We had a bunch of talks at the beginning on what this site would be about and around moderation in general.

I've listen, relaxed what I would have closed as too borderline too see where it goes and well, it doesn't go toward something I'm interested in anymore. 
A fair amount of questions show no understanding and doesn't show research of what they're doing and I didn't join for hand holding.

So I've taken the decision to step down as moderator and mostly to take a break of StackExchange as a whole.

In addition, [this goes beyong Devops.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/287976) alone, I've kept this post focused on here, but StackExchange behavior is a a large part of why I'm resigning and leaving this network. This now takes effect immediately (2019-09-30), I won't handle any more flag.

Was fun, take care of you all  :)

P.S: Mod elections should come in a near future, meanwhile I'll still be around, but far less active.

Comment: Huge Thanks for all your efforts, crucial for bringing the DevOps site from its inception to where it is today!!!

Comment: I'm tempted to *downvote* this question ... especially because on meta sites downvotes are used to indicate disagreement with the post. Howver, since it is TB who posted this question, and out of respect for how mostly TB, and only TB, performed all those moderation tasks since devops.SE started, I cannot downvote it. Needless to say I fully agree with @DanCornilescu ... PS: how about changing your status to AWL, aka absent-without-leave, hoping to see you back when **you** feel time is right to return? E.g after some weeks / months (not years ...) of (unpayed) vacation? ... SVP?!?!

Comment: You may want to proofread your post as there's numerous clumsy typos, and most of us can't "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites."

Comment: @user1271772 sorry for that, I can't really stop them, blame ESL. I'm unsure bumping this 18 month old post about me leaving for typos would be very useful.

Answer (score 8):

You will be sorely missed.  I'm sorry the volume of clueless questions has worn you out.  That's totally understandable.  Hopefully we can bring out more of what you were hoping for in the community.  Closing more marginal tickets sounds like a worthy plan.

Thank you for your huge contributions to the site.  Noone has earned more rep from the Q&A.  Noone has done more moderation.  These are huge shoes to fill and we are very grateful your huge effort to get us so far.

Good luck with all of your other projects.  I'm glad you had fun with this site for a while.  Hopefully you can easily find some fun somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :)

Answer (score 5):

Sad to see you go. Thank you for all the work you've done and for growing the DevOps SE community to what it is today. Best of luck, and hope to see you elsewhere around the internet :)